# How do I block a loopback connection to some port on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, network-programming, loopback

Adding an inbound Windows Firewall rule (via COM from C++) for local port 80 and addresses ANY, 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 does not block a local browser from accessing a local web server running on port 80. For debugging/testing purposes, I need to simulate loss of network connectivity between two programs running on the same computer. Is there a way to do this programmatically, on the command line, or with a tool?

In this question, they say allegedly there is no way to do this in the Windows Firewall:

[How do I block localhost connections with the Windows 7/2008R2 firewall?](https://superuser.com/questions/401900/)

Is there a way, other than Windows Firewall, just to simulate loss of network connectivity between programs running on the same computer?

Comment: I'd try to address your own computer not via 127.0.0.1, but via it's real (LAN) IP address. Processing of real IP and loopback usually go via very different paths, so you might be able to block your connection via real IP, despite staying on the same machine. Also note that via firewall you'll be able to simulate only one flavour of connectivity loss (most likely, "blackhole"-style loss).

Comment: It might be easier to use a "network loss simulator proxy" which listens on port A, randomly drops packets and forwards the remainder to port B. Point your webbrowser to port A, and configure the webserver at port B.

Comment: Perhaps run the programs in a pair of virtual machines?

Answer (score 2):

There is [WIPFW](http://wipfw.sourceforge.net) -- a Windows port of FreeBSD's IPFW. However, I failed to get it to block localhost connections. Maybe you'll have more luck.

Alternatively, you can try a hack. If your programs establish a connection using the `localhost` host name instead of directly by the 127.0.0.1 IP address, you may change your [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to point the `localhost` name to some non-existing or otherwise unreachable address.